# PhpStorm takes FOREVER to show saved changes during 'php artisan serve'. Any "fix"?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm, laravel-artisan

I am getting really irritated by how PhpStorm does things.

I'm serving the application doing `php artisan serve` and then I'm editing the files within PhpStorm IDE. I made it so that I have to manually save it, because I just hate the autosave features of PhpStorm.

Anyways, whenever I make changes to a webpage and save, it takes AGES (okay maybe like 15-30 seconds. But that's a relatively long duration) for it to actually show up on my local server when viewing on Chrome (And it can't be a caching issue since I use `CTRL+F5` to clear the cache).

Like I literally can stop `php artisan serve` and then restart `php artisan serve` to see the changes before it updates by itself...

Why is this so? What IDE do you recommend me using, if this is something I have to live with using PhpStorm?

(I'm editing a Laravel Framework app, on a Bitnami WAMPstack.)

Comment: Some context (*what* are you saving) and clarification (define "ages") would be helpful. Also, this sounds like a caching problem, not a PHPStorm problem. What have you checked so far?

Comment: Ok, i'll add in more context. And I'm quite sure it isn't a caching problem, as I CTRL+F5 in chrome to refresh the page (which removes cache before sending a new request).

Comment: I don't necessarily mean browser caching. It could be cached at a lot of other levels, including by your application itself. Some clarification on what your app is and what it's doing would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize other cache could cause it. Anyways I updated with the following info: (I'm editing a Laravel Framework app, on a Bitnami WAMPstack.) // but wouldn't it still be basically immediate once i saved changes to some files? the Laravel is pretty much a fresh installation...

Comment: Are you using OpCache or something?

Comment: Wow. I found OPCache in the php.ini file and it was enabled by default. Thanks so much.

Comment: Try changing your OPCache settings so it checks for file changes more often (e.g. every 5 seconds or so instead of once per minute). This way you will have benefits of having OPCache enabled + no caching issue.

Comment: @LazyOne sounds like a good idea. Is it not good to disable opcache altogether?

Comment: It's up to you. If you are happy with the way/speed how it works without OPCache (at the end of the day it's development environment so it can be slower) .. then disabling it is the safest option. I have it enabled and do not see any issues (and I do see better exec speed as compared when it's disabled)

Comment: It sounds like you have already solved your problem. If not, you might find this helpful: https://community.bitnami.com/t/wamp-php-file-not-updating/40883